# What should I know before plastering a concrete pool?

Tags: plaster, pool

These two videos do *not* make it seem extremely difficult to replaster the pool for, say me and a friend:

[Swimming Pool Plastering Process (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61U2OoL7k0I)

[Marble Dusting A Pool Also Known As Pool Plastering (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbBvZJRU1Qw)

Seems that I can rent all the tools from Home Depot?

What should I know prior to making the move and buying that plaster (I am thinking DiamondBrite [for about $20 for 80lb](http://www.nexusdinc.com/pool-finish/diamond-brite.html?mode=list) that each cover 25 sq ft, unless you advise otherwise)?

It is a concrete kidney shape pool of about 2K sq feet that just took an acid wash.

After reading a [great article](http://www.truetex.com/pool.htm) by Richard J. Kinch, I can break down "difficulties" to several stages:

- Choosing or making/mixing you own plaster
- Old plaster is no eager-to-bond, hence needs either a "bonding layer" or to be taken out in places where it's loose
- Mixing plaster and water with no lumps
- Delivering mixed plaster to a pool
- Managing the time between mixing and applying
- Splitting pool in less risky to more risky/difficult sections to learn gradually
- Avoid "hot" joins [related to "timing"]
- Striving for a uniformed thickness

These are just the few. Any others you would suggest? Or maybe solutions to the above.

Comment: Good luck, I think its going to be a rewarding challenge, Cannot comment on building techniques, but if its a re-plaster job make sure the end finish is not too abrasive, as it will hurt your feet and attract algae. Also, have you considered re-coating with fibreglass?, It has many advantages over Marbelite/cement when considering coating. ps. what is the current finish?

Comment: Plastering a wall is INCREDIBLY hard to do without extensive practice.  Well it is easy but hard to make look "right".  Other than screwing up a mix or having a bad seam - which a catastrophic and would include demo and redo, plaster is an art.  I have plastered 15-20 times in my life, and 15-20 times it looks like a person with no experience plastering did the work.  I think the biggest concern is how to do plaster evenly and smooth over such a large section.

Answer (score 1):

Having done some plaster, but only on interior walls (not drywall, real plaster), and some finish concrete and masonry work, I have to say that the most useful thing you can do is build yourself some sample surfaces and try to learn there.  Actually hardened materials are a major pain to remove, and will look awful if you do a poor job.

Remember that a great deal of the strength in the surface comes from the chemical reactions (including oxidation) in the materials.  Therefore, you really need to have the moisture levels right.  A big challenge when plastering is making sure that the underlying layer doesn't suck the water out of your mix, which will cause the layer you're putting on to fail (because it's too dry when setting up).  Mist the surface carefully: too wet is just as bad as too dry.  (Ask me how I know.  Go ahead, ask ;-))

The remark from DMoore is also right: a smooth appearance over the area is quite important.  Building some guides that allow you to check for high and low spots when you're still wet will make your life easier.  I haven't done anything nearly as large as a pool, but this made my life much easier in large sections of wall that needed to be repaired in a historic building.

I watched the old-timey pros do some plaster over a brick wall in my last house, and it appears to me that the trick for seams is to have the assistant mixing batches to time thing just so.  That way, the edge of the work you're just finishing is still fresh when the new mix shows up, and you never really have a definite seam (this is the "hot joins" bit you mention).  Of course, to make this work you basically have to do the whole job in one go.  Hard to do, if it's big enough.  If you're doing this for the first time, I think planning to do this with only two of you will result in not being able to do that.

Do *not* neglect keeping the work clean as you go.  You can make a pretty good job look like total crap by having stray bits of mess hanging around, and hardened Portland cement is very hard to clean up.  (You can do it with polishing and so on, but it's way better to get as clean as close as possible in the first place.)

If you can find some smallish and nice finish-concrete or finish-plaster problem to try doing first, your hand and eye with the trowels will be way better when you get to this much bigger job.  If you can learn to love wavy bits in your finished work, then learning as you go might be ok.  But if you can try to learn in some smaller jobs first, I bet your life will be better.  I wish I could go back in time and re-do the first ceiling re-plaster I did, because I could see how I got better as I went across the ceiling (I was out of time because my wife wanted me to cook something rather than butter the ceiling some more!).

Good luck.